# UIAlert not working under UIWebView

Tags: ios, rubymotion

If my app is in the background, i can receive the notification alert.

But if my app is in the foreground and focus on the UIWebView the alert window won't show content

any idea? Thanks so much

```
def application(application, didReceiveRemoteNotification: user_info)  
  alert_log(user_info[:some_extra_data])
end    

def alert_log(message)
alert = UIAlertView.new 
alert.message = message
alert.delegate = self
alert.show 
end
```

## As you can see the bg became grayed, and popup has no message. it can not be dismissed too

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use UIAlertController instead, UIAlertView was deprecated in iOS8, probably what’s causing your problem

Comment: Thanks so much I'll try that